# Finding Coordinates & size of a solid object in an image using php

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am trying to see if it is possible to automatically detect from an image, if the color of the pixel matches what we want (in this case the purple you can see) then it should return the x,y coordinates the purple box starts at, and its dimensions. This should continue until it is finished then display the results.

See image I want to process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6xQk.png

I understand the theory I just loop through all pixels until I find purple, then go up, down, left right to find the bounding box, then continue, taking note to collect a list of pixels that I have already matched to a box.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this : http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php

```
$image = new Imagick('testimage.jpg');
$x = 1;
$y = 1;
$pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor($x, $y);
```

And so you can do for loop like this :

```
//Pseudo-CODE
myX = -1;
myY = -1;
for(x = 0 -> width)
    for(y = 0 -> height)
    {
        if(getImagePixelColor(x,y) == color)
        {
            myX = x;
            myY = y;
        }
        else
        {
            if(myX != -1 && myY != -1 && getImagePixelColor(x,y) == white && getImagePixelColor(x - 1,y - 1) == color && getImagePixelColor(x - 1,y) == white && getImagePixelColor(x,y - 1) == white)
            {
                myWidth = x - myX;
                myHeight = y - myY;
                //You probably should stop the loop here ;)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats a great start, thank you. I guess whast missing and I will have to work on is the array to store found rectangles, also the code once a pixel is found with the correct color to determine the boundaries of the rectangle also

Comment: To find the end of a rectangle, is simply : check if the current pixel is white, the pixel in top left of the current pixel checked (x,y) have the same color that the first pixel found and the pixel on left and on top are white.
With this 4 conditions, you sure you're at the end :)

Comment: I've upgrade the pseudo code :) You will find a rectangle with this.
If you've some rectangle, just adapt the begin of your for loops.

(Sorry for my bad english, i'm french ;D)